# How to use multiple db2 databases in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, db2

Currently i use the package cooperl/laravel-db2 for the database connection. For my project, i should to toggle schema database.

I try this in db2.php :

```
'connections' => [

        'ibmi_1' => [
            ...
            'host' => '***********',
            'username' => '***********',
            'password' => '***********',
            'database' => 'database',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'schema_1',
            'port' => *****,
            'date_format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
            ...
        ],

        'ibmi_2' => [
            ...
            'host' => '***********',
            'username' => '***********',
            'password' => '***********',
            'database' => 'database',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'schema_2',
            'port' => *****,
            ...
        ],
```

And this in .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=ibmi_1
DB_HOST=
DB_PORT=
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_CONNECTION=ibmi_2
DB_HOST=
DB_PORT=
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

But when i try in tinker

```
DB::connection('ibmi_2')
```

I have this error

```
InvalidArgumentException with message 'Database connection [ibmi_2] not configured.'
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Something needs restarting? or pointing to different config files ?

Comment: the database configuration wasn't in bootstrap/cache/config.php ! thank you for your advice ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the database configuration wasn't in bootstrap/cache/config.php.